# Decision tree in JSON - return leaf to root path for a given leaf

Tags: python, json, decision-tree

I have a **decision tree** in a **json format** (about **11k** nodes) and need to have a function which returns a **path from a given leaf to root**.
Before coding this from scratch, do you know if there exists any python json format based code that returns such path?
For example, if **"Predict: 59.0"** is my leaf, when I run getMyPath("Predict: 59.0") I'd like to receive something like below:

```
{
  "name": "Root",
  "children": [
    {
      "name": "x<= 0.09",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "y<= 281.0",
          "children": [
            {
              "name": "z<= 217.75400000000002",
              "children": [
                {
                  "name": "z<= -0.01",
                  "children": [
                    {
                      "name": "z<= -64.83",
                      "children": [
                        {
                          "name": "Predict: 59.0"
```

Thanks, Michal

Answer (score 0):

Nope, you'll have to write a recursive function to look through each and every path of the decision tree structure.